# Can't download attachments from Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I have setup Google app for my domain email addresses (email@mydomain.com). Everything is working fine but one thing. I am not being able to download attachments from my mails. When clicking the download link the connection just gets timed out. But I can still read doc files via Google doc reader.

**Error:**

`The connection has timed out.
          The server at mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com is taking too long to respond.`

Can anyone advice? May be I have to change something in my Google Apps account?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're the "owner" of the domain you created. Sometimes this changes things a bit. I was an admin for a site that I was writing a script for, then one day I was no longer listed as an owner of the site and couldn't access google apps script. This might affect your mail account at that domain.

Comment: How do i make sure of that? Sorry, I am new to google app. Although i have verify me as a owner of the website by adding meta tag to my site.

Comment: If you go to google.com/a/"yourdomain.com" and go to the "Organization and Users" section. Then hit make sure you're an administrator, which you would be if you have access to this dashboard. But then if you say you are the owner of your site (go to example.com>more actions>site permissions>and a pop-up will appear. Your name should be on that with a "is owner" tag next to it). If this is already the case then I don't know what else it could be. Sorry.

Comment: When I go to "Organization and Users" I see the Status of my email as administrator next to email account. But no site permission link on "More Action" drop down list :(